# Angular Universal Prerender with angular Localization i18n deploy to IIS

Tags: angular, iis, angular-universal, angular15, angular-localize

I am using Angular 15,, with universal, ,and angular localization....

Before using angular localization I was able to deploy the app successfully by moving whatever in the server file into the root of my website,,,and keep the deployed structure as it is .

my files were like this

- app-root
- main.js
- dist
- ```
     app-name
  ```
- ```
         browser folder
  ```

That was working fine with this web.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <match url="/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="StaticContent" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="([\S]+[.](jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ts|cscc|less|ico|html|map|svg))" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
            <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
            <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/otf" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: c5d98956-83c1-4844-9adc-6eb88f08e103-->
```

No After adding angular localization the project structure got changed after build
where the server folder now contains extra 2 folder for the supported locals ,, in my case  ar and en... also the browser folder has one folder inside it which is en...

And of course, my initial package won't work... how to solve this issue I need help..

thanks

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your problem clearly. What do you mean by the initial package not working? Vague descriptions alone do not allow community members to understand the problem you are experiencing. Please post more details information about your issue.

Comment: Hello, If you didn't solve it yet, I can help you to resolve it, today I had the same issue but with the build process. you need to do some changes to the express